# Is the completion of an injective local homomorphism still injective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, completion

Let $R$ be a regular local ring (say of dimension 2) with quotient field $F$. Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring with the same quotient field such that $R\subset A\subset F$, $A\neq F$. Let $\hat{R}$ and $\hat{A}$ be the completions with respect to the respective maximal ideals, and suppose that the inclusion $R\subset A$ is a local homomorphism (i.e. the maximal ideal of $A$ restricts to that of $R$).

Question: Is the induced map $\hat{R}\to \hat{A}$ necessarily injective ? (By assumption, the $\mathfrak{m}_R$-adic topology on $R$ is finer than (the subspace topology of) the $\mathfrak{m}_A$-adic topology. So the quotient is: are the two topologies the same ?)

Comment: No. Let $R$ be a countable regular local ring of dimension 2, so by countable prime avoidance (as in my recent answer to a question about stale vs. fpqc topologies) there are uncountably many height-1 primes of the completion. Hence, there is a height-1 prime $P$ of the completion not over a height-1 prime of $R$, so $P$ lies over (0). Let $A$ be the normalization of the 1-dimensional complete local noetherian domain $\widehat{R}/P$; it is a complete DVR which does the job.

Comment: @nfdc23: The OP asks that $A$ be a subring of the fraction field of the regular local ring.  Are you suggesting to define $A$ to be the valuation ring of the restriction of the valuation to $R \subset (\widehat{R}/P)$?

Comment: @nfdc23,@Jason Starr, with $A$ defined as mentioned in Jason's message, I think it works. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant to work with the induced dvr on the fraction field of $R$ (and where wrote "stale" I meant "etale" but auto-correct seemed to think it knew better). When it came to then writing my initial comment, I forgot about the condition that $A$ is meant to be inside the fraction field.